# Get all the texts in h2 and return an array readable (via APIFY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, apify

I'm using "Web scraper apify" to scrap some data from a website. The goal is to get all the texts in H2 and return an array of them. My problem is when I returned the array. This one is not correct and not usable because it separates all the letters of the different scrapped texts.

I tried to write this code (javascript and jquery including):

```js
function pageFunction() {
  const results = []

  $('h2').map(function() {
    results.push($(this).text());
  });

  return results;
}

console.log(pageFunction());
```

```html
<h2>Heading One</h2>
<h2>Heading Two</h2>
<h2>Heading Three</h2>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And I have this result when I export in JSON

```
[{
  "0": "M",
  "1": "u",
  "2": "t",
  "3": "i",
  "4": "n",
  "5": "y"
},
{
  "0": "G",
  "1": "r",
  "2": "o",
  "3": "w",
  "4": "S",
  "5": "u",
  "6": "m",
  "7": "o"
},
{
  "0": "C",
  "1": "u",
  "2": "s",
  "3": "t",
  "4": "o",
  "5": "m",
  "6": "e",
  "7": "r",
  "8": ".",
  "9": "i",
  "10": "o"
}]
```

I would like something like

```
[{
"tool": "Mutiny"
},
{
"tool": "Growsumo"
},
{
"tool":"customer.io"
}]
```

Comment: Not causing your issue, but worth mentioning:  You're incorrectly using `.map` as a `.each` - use map correctly:  `results = $("h2").map(function() { $(this).text() })`

Comment: Please revise the demo I created so it gives the output you've shown.

Comment: It looks like an issue with how you stringify to JSON (which you've not included) rather than how you generate the array.  There's no reference to `"tool"` in your code, so unclear how you expect that to appear in the output.

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m . I've just tried your script (reviewed) directly in the console and it works well. You're right, there is an issue with the stringify JSON . 
About the reference "tool", it was more an expectation but not important. 
Do you know how to stringify correctly the json via the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the cause of the string being split to a character array, to get the desired output, change the `map` so that it returns the object that you want, rather than just the text:

```
.map((i, e) => $(e).text())
```

gives you an array of the text, but you want an array of `{ tool: <text> }`, so:

```
.map((i, e) => { return { tool : $(e).text() } })
```

(note: jquery .map() requires .get() at the end to convert to a "true" array)

You'll then have an array of objects, which you can json stringify to get your desired JSON output:

```js
let results = $('h2').map((i, e) => { 
    return { tool: $(e).text() }
}).get();

//console.log(results);

let json = JSON.stringify(results)

console.log(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Mutiny</h2>
<h2>Growsumo</h2>
<h2>Customer.io</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks for all details  .

Answer (score 0):

Results saved to Storage by `Apify.pushData(returnedObject)` and if your data object is array then SDK will save it as multiple items, therefore array item must be JSON, you must `.push({tool: $(this).text()})`